# I need Linq Query for this SQL Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
"select count(salary) from employee where employeeID = 10 group by salary" --- Its a SQL  Query.
```

I need Linq Query which would retrieve me same output..?

Please Help me out i am new to Linq

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 4):

You should also check :

[image]

Full aricle : [SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

```
from e in employee
where e.employeeid=10
group e by e.Salary
              into grp
              select new
              {
                  Salary = grp.Key,
                  Count = grp.Count()
              };
```

Comment: the original SQL only returns the count. Why do you also return Country/the key of the group? (which in you code is only named btw since the field is called salary)

Answer (score 0):

Your query puzzles me from the functional perspective: You want to count the number of different salaries for one employee?

Anyway, i think something like this would do also work (untested)

```
db.Employees.Where(e=>e.id == 10).Select(s=>s.salary).Distinct().Count()
```